# Herencia y asignación de objetos

Tags: java

Tengo estas dos clases:

```
class A extends Alpha{
 public A(int x, int y){
  super(x,y);
 }

 public void transformar(){
  this = new B(this.x,this.y);
}

class B extends A{

 public B(int x, int y){
  super(x,y);
}
```

Cuando invoco el método transformar, este no puede compilar y da el siguiente error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

¿Como podría solventarlo?

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que te falla en esa parte solo? ¿No podrías mostrar todo el código? El error que te sale es porque probablemente estés intentando asignar un valor en un campo que no es una variable, puede que tengas mal los constructores.

Comment: El código no tiene sentido, una instancia no puede auto-asignarse para ser otra instancia (y mucho menos de otra clase). ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: El objetivo es que mi objeto de tipo A pase a ser una de tipo B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que intentas no tiene sentido, lo que sí puedes hacer es:

```
A obj = new B(1,0);
```

O incluso podrías hacer:

```
Alpha obj = new A(1,0);
Alpha obj2 = new B(1,0);
```

Porque todo objeto de la clase B es un objeto de la clase A y todo objeto de la clase A es una objeto de la clase Alpha. Así es como funciona la jerarquía de clases.

Pero no puedes hacer que una instancia de una clase deje de pertenecer a esa clase, rompería muchas cosas.